# How can i set binding to childproperty from App.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, telerik, inotifypropertychanged

I have a problem with my Binding to a ListBox Control.
Actually i have a Property in App.xaml.cs :

```
public partial class App : Application, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ObservableCollection<Panier> _panier = new ObservableCollection<Panier>();

    public ObservableCollection<Panier> PanierProperty
    {
        get { return _panier; }
        set
        {
            if (this._panier != value)
            {
                this._panier = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("PanierProperty");
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

this property have a child properties in the "Panier class" here:

```
public class Panier : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _nom;
    private string _category;
    private int _prix;

    public string Nom
    {
        get { return _nom; }
        set
        {
            if (this._nom != value)
            {
                this._nom = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Nom");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Category
    {
        get { return _category; }
        set
        {
            if (this._category != value)
            {
                this._category = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Category");
            }
        }
    }

    public int Prix
    {
        get { return _prix; }
        set
        {
            if (this._prix != value)
            {
                this._prix = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Prix");
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

and in my MainWindow.xaml page i have my ListBox bound to PanierProperty(parent property) :

```
<telerik:RadListBox x:Name="PanierLB" Grid.Row="1" Height="200" Width="350" Margin="0 300 0 0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding PanierProperty, Source={x:Static Application.Current}}"
    DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=PanierProperty.Nom, Source={x:Static Application.Current}}">
</telerik:RadListBox>
```

my problem is that PanierProperty is bound to my Listbox i see items in the listbox like Design.Panier
Design.Panier
Design.Panier
etc...
I dont know how to get the PanierProperty.Nom(Nom is the child property) to show on the ListBox.

Someone can help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `DisplayMemberPath` use the name of property you want to show only:

```
<telerik:RadListBox
    ...
    DisplayMemberPath="Nom"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it drives me crazy :s i was only trying with {Binding Nom} didn't knew that Thanks :D